# wrong number of arguments (2 for 0..1) at redirect_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arguments

## Error image

[argument error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5oXjC.png)

home_controller.rb

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController

def home
 @activities = Activity.order("created_at DESC").page(params[:page]).per_page(5)
end

def login
  render 
end

def logout
  session[:school_id] = nil
  session[:parent_id] = nil
  session[:user_id] = nil

  redirect_to :controller => 'home', :action => 'login'
end
```

Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails', '4.2.4'
gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.3.20'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
gem 'remotipart', '~> 1.2'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.5'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'bootstrap_form'
gem 'devise', '~> 3.5', '>= 3.5.2'
gem 'bartt-ssl_requirement', '~>1.4.0', :require => 'ssl_requirement'
gem 'will_paginate'
gem 'paperclip'
gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'
group :development, :test do
 console
  gem 'byebug'
end
```

Comment: Your code looks correct, and the method parameters should be passed in as a single argument. What happens when you surround the argument with parenthesis:  `redirect_to(:controller => 'home', :action => 'login')`  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to explain the redirect_to actually expects a path not controller or action and Helsing has answered it very beautifully that how can you make a route out of controller and its action.

Answer (score 2):

```
redirect_to :controller => 'home', :action => 'login'
```

This is not correct, not to mention ugly. Instead, create a route in routes.rb that does that action. For example:

```
get 'login' => 'home#login'
```

Then you would use:

```
redirect_to login_path
```

**BONUS**

****You should read up on rails routing to make better routes too.****

Also, a home controller that handles logins does not seem very clean.

A better route would be something like the following but it requires different controller setup:

```
resources :sessions
```

which creates the following route and many others(not exactly but lets ignore the details):

```
get 'login' => 'sessions#new'
```

Again, I recommend you read up on [Rails routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html).

Comment: thanx a lot, creating route solved the problem. Also i'm new to ruby, for sure i'll go through the rails routing before proceeding further. Thanx for the recommendation bro.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me that you may have had your code written incorrectly initially, and even though you've fixed the source code, Rails is still using the old (incorrect) version.

You must have had some variant of:

```
redirect_to 'home', :action => 'login'
redirect_to 'home', 'login'
```

before.

Leave your code the way you have it (`redirect_to(:controller => 'home', :action => 'login')`), and make sure you restart your Rails process correctly.